# Jest and enzyme - how to test function that is property to child component (for test coverage)

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, test-coverage

To simplify - I have a component, let say `<Label />` and I'm using it like this:

```
...
<Label
  labelText="Some text"
  renderText={(text) => {
    const cssClass = text.length < 5 ? 'one-class' : 'other-class';
    return <b className={cssClass}>{text}</b>;
  }}
/>
...
```

So - I have a property which is a function that defines how the text will be displayed. All is fine and it's working.

When I run `jest --coverage` however - it shows me that the line with setting `cssClass` is uncovered.

How can I test that line?

Comment: Are you testing both sides of the [conditional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)?  (testing both when `text.length` is less than 5 and when it is greator or equal to 5?)

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how to test that `renderText` function / property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways testing that. And you need 2 test-cases: one for `text.length< 5` and another one for `text.length>= 5`

First aprroach is using `mount()`. Here you need to figure out where `text` argument is coming from(passing as a `props` to your component or what's the way). Then you will get `<Label>` rendered in some `<span>` or whatever. And you will need to check if there is inside `<b class='one-class'>text</b>` or `<b class='other-class'>text1</b>`

Another approach is using `shallow()` on your component. Then you will be able to test `renderText` explicitly:

```
it('renders label with text having length of 4', () => {
  const renderText = shallow(<YourComponent ... >).find(Label).props().renderText;
  expect(renderText('1234')).toEqual(<b className="one-class">1234</b>);
});

it('renders label with text having length of 5 or more', () => {
  const renderText = shallow(<YourComponent ... >).find(Label).props().renderText;
  expect(renderText('12345')).toEqual(<b className="other-class">12345</b>);
});
```